# WPF Controls as StaticResource in Resource Dictionary, used in multiple WPF Windows?

Tags: wpf, xaml, .net-4.0, resourcedictionary, staticresource

I have a Button control as a resource in Resource Dictionary as below:

```
<!--ButtonResources.xaml file-->
<ResourceDictionary 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Button x:Key="buttonResource" Content={Binding BoundText}/>
</ResourceDictionary>
<!--ButtonResources.xaml file-->
```

I now use this above button control **bound to Content property of ContentControl controls** in **2 different Windows** .xaml files where each `Window` has its own `DataContext` and thus each window should display the `Content` of above button control based on its `ViewModel's` `BoundText` property value as below for each Window.

```
<Window x:Class="TestClass1" 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="ButtonResources.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ContentControl Content={StaticResource buttonResource}/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

But, the problem is that both Window's display same value for the BoundText property which means that both the WPF Windows have ***same*** instance of button control from resource, used in both the Windows.

How can I resolve this problem such that each Window gets a *separate* button control from the resource and still display ***different*** values for the `BoundText` property from their **own ViewModel**?

**Edit:**
For the reason mentioned in `MSDN` as below, I can't use x:Shared="False" attribute to resolve this:

> •The ResourceDictionary that contains the items must not be nested
>   within another ResourceDictionary. For example, you cannot use
>   x:Shared for items in a ResourceDictionary that is within a Style that
>   is already a ResourceDictionary item.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you try to use the `x:Shared` attribute?

```
<ResourceDictionary 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Button x:Shared="False" x:Key="buttonResource" Content={Binding BoundText}/>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

For more info read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970778.aspx).

In case this does not work, you can store a template in your resource, instead of the button and use a ContentControl inside your window to display it.

Comment: Thanks. But, I can't use that attribute as reason mentioned in my **Edit:** part of the question.

Comment: And you use the above example you would use the following tag.                   <StaticResource ResourceKey="buttonResource" />

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="buttonResource">
    <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding BoundText}" />
</Style>
```

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource buttonResource}" />
```

Comment: Thanks. I updated my question to include the usage of Content Control, how do I bind the ContentControl in each WPF Window (.xaml) to Button resource in resource dictionary as per above answer?

Comment: I don't see how that would be different. Can you post the code of your ContentControl?

Comment: I added the code for usage of ContentControl in both Window.xaml files.. The actual usage is not of a button but a different control and its because we want to change the resource xaml file in future versions without having to change the Window.xaml file code...

Comment: In the example I wrote buttonResource is no longer a Button, but a style, so you can't use it for the Content property of a ContentControl. In that case you should try the example code from @Alex and set the x:Shared attribute to false.